# Illegal offset type in Zend Framework 1 when using dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I've researched illegal offset types but can't seem to get to the bottom of this one.

I have a script that selects `id` from table `linkages` column `id` and returning an array `$resultid`.

In the second part of my script I have a loop that is selecting `content` from `latestRevision` where `$linktagId is equal to $id`.

When I declare `$id = $resultid` and the $resultid has more than one value, I get Warning:

```
Illegal offset type ... on line 252
```

line 252 :

```
$result[$lId] = $stmt->fetch();
```

But if i limit the values in the original array to one by changing fetchAll to Fetch it runs fine.

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
public function testAction()

{
    //Return list of tags for the defined user and make default type 10
    $u = 2;
    $t = 10;

    $resultid = array();

    //Connect to database
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select()
        ->from(array('lt' => 'Linktags'),
            array('id'))
        ->where('userId = ?', $u)
        ->where('type = ?', $t);

    $stmt = $select->query();
    $resultid = $stmt->fetchAll();


   //print_r($resultid);

    //Get latest revision from database and loop through $id's

    $id = $resultid;

    //print_r($id);

    //setup array and loop

    $result = array();

    foreach($id as $lId) {

        //Connect to database

        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

        //Perform Query
        $select = $db->select('')
            ->from(array('lr'=>'LinktagRevisions'),
            array('content'))
            ->where('linktagId = ?', $lId)
            ->order('updated DESC')
            ->limit(1);


        $stmt = $select->query();
        $result[$lId] = $stmt->fetch();


    }

    $this->_helper->json($result,true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `fetchAll` will return an array of arrays.
So `$lId` is an array.

Try something like this :

```
foreach($id as $lId_all) {
    $lId = $lId_all[0];
    ....
```

Or

```
foreach($id as $lId_all) {
    foreach($lId_all as $lId) {
    ....
```

Comment: fyi, another way of 'losing' the 'outer' array, which is only one entry, is to use 'current($lId)'. This will return  the 'inner' array. i.e. foreach(current($lId) as $id );  It takes advantage of the the 'inbult array iterator' that all 'arrays' have.

Comment: @doydoy44 You are the man! Thats twice in one day you have helped me, thank you very much. It was the second suggestion that worked.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent - I tried this suggestion, it removed the error but would only return one result. Thank you for helping.

Comment: sorry about that. - i should have tested it.